# How to pass the values of variables from a form in HTML to a jquery script?

Tags: jquery, html

I would need to know how to pass the values of the variables reportId and apiToken from the fields of a form in the HTML page to the jquery script. Please, see below:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            var reportId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX", // Required
               apiToken = "YYYYYYYYYY", // Required

                containerId = "embeddedReport", // Required

                documentId = "", // Optional
                dateRange = {"mode": "LAST_7_DAYS"}, // Optional
                slicer = {
                        
    }, // Optional

                // Report size
                width = 1000,
                height = 400,

                // leave that variable NULL
                ReportToken = null;

            

            function getReportTokenJS(apiToken, reportId, width, height, containerId) {
                var payLoadData = createPayLoadData();

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) {

                    }
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status >= 200 && xmlhttp.status < 300) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        ReportToken = data.token;
                        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                        iframe.style.width = width + 'px';
                        iframe.style.height = height + 'px';
                        iframe.src = 'https://app.somepage.com/reports/' + ReportToken;
                        document.getElementById(containerId).appendChild(iframe);
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://app.somepage.com/1/embeddedReports", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(payLoadData));


            };

            function createPayLoadData() {
                if (apiToken == "" || apiToken == null || reportId == "" || reportId == null) {
                    console.log("ERROR: apiToken Or reportId is missing");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    var payLoadData = {};
                    payLoadData.apiToken = apiToken;
                    payLoadData.reportId = reportId;
                }

                if (documentId != "" && documentId != null) {
                    payLoadData.documentId = documentId;
                }

                if (Object.keys(dateRange).length > 0) {
                    payLoadData.dateRange = dateRange;
                }

                if (Object.keys(slicer).length > 0) {
                    payLoadData.slicer = slicer;
                }

                return payLoadData;
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

  <button type="button" onclick="getReportTokenJS(apiToken, reportId, width, height, containerId);">generate embedded report</button>
        <div id="embeddedReport"></div>

    

    </body>
 
</html>
```

Please, consider that I found this example somewhere, so I don't really know how to program in jquery. A full working example modifying the code I provide here would be to only way to show me how to do.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help (**"why isn't this code working?"**) must include *the desired behavior*, *a specific problem or error* and *the shortest code necessary* to reproduce it **in the question itself**. Questions without **a clear problem statement** are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1):

Using jQuery, it is very easy to retrieve values from a form using the id of the `input` controls in your form.

So add a unique `id` attribute to each of your input controls.  Then, in your Javascript, access the value of the input control using that id.

Also, you do not need to pass all of the parameters in your `onclick` event handler.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>

<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
        
        <script src="//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js"></script>
        <script>

            var reportId = "XXXXXXXXXXXX", // Required
               apiToken = "YYYYYYYYYY", // Required

                containerId = "embeddedReport", // Required

                documentId = "", // Optional
                dateRange = {"mode": "LAST_7_DAYS"}, // Optional
                slicer = {
                        
    }, // Optional

                // Report size
                width = 1000,
                height = 400,

                // leave that variable NULL
                ReportToken = null;

            

            function getReportTokenJS(apiToken, reportId, width, height, containerId) {
                var payLoadData = createPayLoadData();

                if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
                    xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
                }
                else {// code for IE6, IE5
                    xmlhttp = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
                }
                xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState != 4) {

                    }
                    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4 && xmlhttp.status >= 200 && xmlhttp.status < 300) {
                        var data = JSON.parse(xmlhttp.responseText);
                        ReportToken = data.token;
                        var iframe = document.createElement('iframe');
                        iframe.style.width = width + 'px';
                        iframe.style.height = height + 'px';
                        iframe.src = 'https://app.somepage.com/reports/' + ReportToken;
                        document.getElementById(containerId).appendChild(iframe);
                    }
                }
                xmlhttp.open("POST", "https://app.somepage.com/1/embeddedReports", true);
                xmlhttp.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/json");
                xmlhttp.send(JSON.stringify(payLoadData));


            };

            function createPayLoadData() {
                // Retrieve the values from the form
                var apiToken = $('#apiToken').val();
                var reportId = $('#reportId').val();

                if (apiToken == "" || apiToken == null || reportId == "" || reportId == null) {
                    console.log("ERROR: apiToken Or reportId is missing");
                    return false;
                } else {
                    var payLoadData = {};
                    payLoadData.apiToken = apiToken;
                    payLoadData.reportId = reportId;
                }

                if (documentId != "" && documentId != null) {
                    payLoadData.documentId = documentId;
                }

                if (Object.keys(dateRange).length > 0) {
                    payLoadData.dateRange = dateRange;
                }

                if (Object.keys(slicer).length > 0) {
                    payLoadData.slicer = slicer;
                }

                return payLoadData;
            };
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

  <form>
    <input id="apiToken" />
    <input id="reportId" />
  </form>

  <button type="button" onclick="getReportTokenJS();">generate embedded report</button>
        <div id="embeddedReport"></div>

    

    </body>
 
</html>
```

Comment: I just found from the console that: file://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js Failed to load resource: net::ERR_FILE_NOT_FOUND How can I fix this?

Comment: Change the script library src attribute to start with https://.  So it should become https:// code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.0.min.js

Answer (score 1):

Since you're new to jQuery and HTML I will try to explain everything in a code snippet.

```js
var reportId = "XXXXXXXXXX",
    apiToken = "YYYYYYYYYY",
    ReportToken = null,
    width = 100,
    height = 100;

function getResponseTokenJS() {
  var payLoadData = createPayloadData();  // A function we'll create later. It returns either an object or a false boolean value.
  if (payLoadData != false) {
     $.ajax({  // jQuery's syntax for creating AJAX requests
       url: "https://app.somepage.com/1/embeddedReports",
       type: "POST",
       contentType: "application/json",
       dataType: "json",
       data: payLoadData,
       success: function(data) {  // if it succeeds with data
         this.ResponseToken = data.token;
         $('#embeddedReport').append("<iframe src='https://app.somepage.com/reports/'"+this.ResponseToken)+" width=" + this.width + " height=" + this.height);
       }
     }); 
  }
}

function createPayloadData() {
   if (this.apiToken=="" || this.apiToken==null || this.reportId=="" || this.reportId==null) {
     // If any of the two values do not instantiate with values...
     console.log("ERROR: missing apiToken or reportId");
     return false;
   }
  else {
    var payloadData = {};
    payloadData.apiToken = this.apiToken;
    payloadData.reportId = this.reportId;
    return false;
  }
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8"/>
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <title>Pass the values of a variable</title>
</head>
  
<body>
  <button type="button" class="embed" onclick="getReportTokenJS()">Generate Embedded Report</button>
  <div id="embeddedReport"></div>
</body>
```

Since the url is not valid, please implement and lemme know if it works or not